# How can I mask a cell with ***** using jxl

Tags: java, jxl

I'm generating an excel using Jxl and I need to mask a cell which will be used to contain a password. In excel this can be done by formating your cell to a custom format type: ";;;**".

Does anyone know how can I do this using Jxl?

Thanks in advance.